# Is there a bookmarks feature in Geany?

Tags: plugins, geany

I have C++ code with more than 10,000 lines. I am looking for something which stores some lines. Like bookmarking some lines or some functions in order to facilitate access to them.

For example, a list which contains bookmark lines or functions.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is the normal way to create bookmarks in Geany:

> Bookmarks
>
> Geany provides a handy bookmarking feature that lets you mark one or
>   more lines in a document, and return the cursor to them using a key
>   combination.
>
> To place a mark on a line, either left-mouse-click in the left margin
>   of the editor window, or else use Ctrl-m. This will produce a small
>   green plus symbol in the margin. You can have as many marks in a
>   document as you like. Click again (or use Ctrl-m again) to remove the
>   bookmark. To remove all the marks in a given document, use "Remove
>   Markers" in the Document menu.
>
> To navigate down your document, jumping from one mark to the next, use
>   Ctrl-. (control period). To go in the opposite direction on the page,
>   use Ctrl-, (control comma). Using the bookmarking feature together
>   with the commands to switch from one editor tab to another
>   (Ctrl-PgUp/PgDn and Ctrl-Tab) provides a particularly fast way to
>   navigate around multiple files.

[Source](http://www.geany.org/manual/current/#bookmarks)

To add a list of these bookmarks, you have to install the Geany plugin *"[Addons](https://plugins.geany.org/addons.html)"*:

```
sudo apt-get install geany-plugin-addons
```

To remember the bookmarks at each file load, the plugin *"[Numbered Booksmarks](https://plugins.geany.org/geanynumberedbookmarks.html)"* is required:

```
sudo apt-get install geany-plugin-numberedbookmarks
```

(You have to save the file if you want save the bookmarks.)

After the installation, enable the plugin to load at startup:

[image]

Next step: Activate the bookmarklist -

[image]

Bookmarklist example:

[image]

Comment: If you don't need the sidebar list, then you don't need the Addons plugin.

Answer (score 3):

As a recent and enthusiastic adopter of Geany (migrating from Windows/Notepad++, which I think Geany already beats!), who has been dealing a lot with bookmarks, I have some additions/caveats to the existing answer - for the benefit of people who arrive from a search engine, since this thread is quite high up the list. These are in relation to the two plugins it mentions and I think important to note:

1. Bookmarks Sidebar does not update when bookmarked lines are moved up or down, using the current version of Addons. I reported this as a bug - and the response from the Geany team was immediate, so there's already a pull on SourceForge - which I've compiled and can confirm fixes it flawlessly. :-) I assume this'll be in the next release.
2. The Numbered Bookmarks plugin, to save changed bookmarks/folds, requires the source file be saved - so if we've finished typing, saved, then change bookmarks/folds - we must re-save, which requires enabling Preferences/Various/`allow_always_save` (allow saving files not marked changed), or make 'dummy' edit to re-save. I am trying to log a FR to have bookmarks/folds auto-saved, or - maybe better (if not bad design/UX) - mark the file changed so we can see and choose whether to save them.

Comment: `allow_always_save` now called `files.allow_always_save`